# Unable to serve a file to download in IE from Angular

Tags: angular, file, typescript, internet-explorer, download

I'm trying to produce a text file to my users and the code below does the job perfectly well in all browsers except IE and Edge (in the latter, I can't control the file's name but it's at least produced).

```
emitFile(stage: any): void {
  const blob = new Blob([stage.elaboration], { type: "text/csv" });
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.href = url;
  anchor.download = "ff-rocks-ie-sucks.txt";
  anchor.click();
}
```

There's [an open issue ticket](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7260192/) in that regard but it's dated 18 months back and the recent activity is rather un-recent. It seems that it's a place where hopes come to die.

I haven't found any reasonable workarounds. The ones I've seen were either non-working or included a (very wise but infeasible) suggestion to get *decent browsers for duck's sake*. And I believe it was more of a typo than a bird reference.

What should be done about it?

Comment: IE11 does not support download attribute. Outcomes in IE differ when using the file: protocol. or localhost.

Comment: And there's no workaround? I was hoping that it's possible to achieve **somehow**. I guess I'm out of luck... Please post it as a reply so it can be (unwillingly) accepted. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should try using msSaveBlob() instead of the download attribute.

```
emitFile(stage: any): void {
  const blob = new Blob([stage.elaboration], { type: "text/csv" });
  window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,"ff-rocks-ie-sucks.txt");
}
```

It should work fine for IE and Edge.

EDIT : 
The full solution for IE, FF and Chrome would be like that :

```
emitFile(stage: any): void {
  const blob = new Blob([stage.elaboration], { type: "text/csv" });
  if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) //IE & Edge
  {
    //msSaveBlob only available for IE & Edge
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,"ff-rocks-ie-sucks.txt");
  }
  else //Chrome & FF
  {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.href = url;
    anchor.download = "ff-rocks-ie-sucks.txt";
    document.body.appendChild(anchor); //For FF
    anchor.click();
    //It's better to remove the elem
    document.body.removeChild(anchor);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that the `emitFile` method should recognize what browser the application is run in and react accordingly? Or is there a way to call the proper version of it based on certain markup?

Comment: No, this solution will only work on IE and Edge because of the msSaveBlob function.
You'll need to add a condition for FF and Chrome :
`if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) //IE & Edge
 { }else{//Chrome & FF}
`